# WordPress Page builder plugin giving Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, wordpress

I have recently installed this page builder plugin and started using it but it returned an error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of ---- bytes exhausted (tried to allocate ---- bytes) in --

Is there any thing I can do about this? I have search here and could not find suitable answer related to wordpress page builder.

Comment: This is more of a server settings related issue. If you have root access in your control panel, go to php settings. Open and edit your php.ini file and change the allowed memory. Some hosts like Godaddy use a checkbox and drop downs to change the memory but most have the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the PHP memory limit. Your WordPress needs more memory in order to complete the task. You will need to edit your wp-config.php file in your public_html (or root of your WordPress) and just after this line in your wp-config.php

```
/* That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

Add this and save the file.

```
define( ‘WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ‘256M’ );
```

Now try again.

Source: https://www.webxen.com/kb/wordpress-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-67108864-bytes-exhausted/